# Use setuptools find_packages to exclude everything except package

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I want to build a package using setup tools. To import package I am using `find_packages` from `setuptools`. I have lots of directory and I want to include only few of them. How can I achieve exclude everything except this directory in find_packages.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

find_packages() # This will return everything
find_packages(exclude=[]) # This will include everything except exclude list
find_packages(where=[]) # this will select a directory but change relative path, so if I include main/src directory and src contain feat_1 then it's path will change to feat_1 whereas it should be src.feat_1
```

Any suggestion how can this be achieved.

Comment: There's also the `include` kwarg to `find_packages()` that will restrict found packages to ones matching the spec in `include`. If you need a working example, add the project directory layout to the question and explicitly state what you want to exclude/include.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for answer. I checked the documentation and figured it out. Some time I really how easier things are if I read documentation.